# how to create a dynamic pick list using JSON schema in Angular

Tags: angular, reactive

I am trying to pass data from a radio button dynamically using ReactiveFormsModule in Angular, this seems to work in StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q1dcxo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

but it doesn't work on my local machine for some reason?!

Comment: Any errors in console in your local machine?